# Mockito: NPE when capturing Spring Data saveOrUpdate() argument

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mockito

I'm trying to unit test a Spring Data repository and to mock its saveOrUpdate() method. The repository is as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    ...
}
```

The unit test:

```
public MyTest {
  ...
  @Mock
  private MyRepository myRepository;
  @Captor
  private ArgumentCaptor<MyEntity> myEntityCaptor;
  ...
  @Test
  public void test123() {
    Mockito.doNothing().when(myRepository).saveOrUpdate(Mockito.any(MyEntity.class));
    MyEntity myEntity = ...;
    myRepository.saveOrUpdate(myEntity);
    Mockito.verify(myRepository).saveOrUpdate(myEntityCaptor.capture());
    assertThat(myEntityCaptor.capture().getId()).isEqualTo(1L);
    ...
}
```

Running the unit test raises NPE on the assert as myEntityCaptor.capture() is null. What am I doing wrong ? Why doesn't the capture work in this case ?

Many thanks in advance.

Seymour

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting stupid things here, I just corrected the line:

```
assertThat(myEntityCaptor.capture().getId()).isEqualTo(1L);
```

to read:

```
assertThat(myEntityCaptor.getValue().getId()).isEqualTo(1L);
```